# Dynamic Programming recursion giving out wrong result

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a variant of Knapsack Problem and have written a recursive solution for it. But my solution is returning a wrong value. I guess my algo is flawed. Can you please help me find the glitch.

Here is my code.

```
int calc_budget(int b, int i){
    // If we have reached the end
    if(i >= nParty){
            tbl[b][i] = 0;
            return tbl[b][i];
    }

    //If remaining capacity is not able to hold the ith capacity, move on to next element
    if(budget[i] > b){
            if(tbl[b][i+1] == 0){
                    tbl[b][i+1] = calc_budget(b,i+1);
            }
            return tbl[b][i+1];
    }
    else{   //If the ith capacity can be accomodated
            //Do not include this item
            if(tbl[b][i+1] == 0){
                    tbl[b][i] = calc_budget(b,i+1);
            }

            // Include this item and consider the next item
            if(tbl[b-budget[i]][i+1] == 0){
                    tbl[b-budget[i]][i] = fun[i] + calc_budget(b-budget[i], i+1);
            }

            // We have the results for includinng ith item as well as excluding ith item. Return the best ( max here )
            return max(tbl[b][i], tbl[b-budget[i]][i]);
    }

}
```

`Objective of the problem: To find the maximum fun by optimally using the given max budget`

Following are my input.

```
budget[3] = {19,12,19}
fun[3] = {2,4,5}
calc_budget(30,0)
allowed budget: 30
```

The correct answer to the program should be 5. Mine is returning 7. I have drawn the recursion tree in the attempt to debug. My findings: While choosing item 0 ( right sub-tree), val = 2 + (11,1). This (11,1) will lead to max ( (11,2) and 0 ). (11,2) is 5 so the final result is 2+5 = 7. In this DP technique my algo should not have chosen 11,2 as sum of the budget exceeds the given one. But this is the basic skeleton I found for a recursive DP. Is this algo flawed or I have mistaken it.

Thanks

Chidambaram

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that during the call `calc_budget(b, i)` you write fields of `tbl` for other indices than `[b][i]`. I will try to explain the issue by using the recursive definition of `calc_budget(b, i)`.

We start by defining the recurrence relation. Let `F(b, i)` be the maximum fun you can have with the parties `i, ..., n` and the maximum budget `b`. Then,

```
F(b, n+1) = 0
F(b, i)   = F(b, i+1) // if budget[i] > b
          = max( F(b, i+1), fun[i] + F(b - budget[i], i+1) ) // otherwise
```

So far so good.`calc_budget(b, i)` should exactly calculate this number, and it should use `tbl` as a cache for already computed values. In other words, after the first time the call `calc_budget(b, i)` is made, `tbl[b][i] == F(b, i)` must be true.

Here's some pseudocode that achieves this:

```
initialize tbl[b][i] = -1 for all b, i.

def calc_budget(b, i):
    if tbl[b][i] != -1: return tbl[b][i]

    if i == n + 1:
        tbl[b][n+1] = 0
    else:
        if budget[i] > b:
            tbl[b][i] = calc_budget(b, i+1)
        else:
            tbl[b][i] = max( 
                            calc_budget(b, i+1), 
                            fun[i] + calc_budget(b - budget[i], i+1)
                           )

    return tbl[b][i]
```

I hope you now agree that since `tbl` is really just a cache for already computed values, it would seem very odd to write e.g. `tbl[b-budget[i]][i]` in a call to `calc_budget(b, i)`.

Answer (score 0):

First, I do not think 0 is good enough to indicate weather a sub problem has been calculated before, because there are some sub problems whose answer is actually 0.
Second, there are a mistake in your code,you should have set the value of tbl[b][i] before you return the value.
Try this:

```
// We have the results for includinng ith item as well as excluding ith item. Return the best ( max here )    
tbl[b][i]=max(tbl[b][i], tbl[b-budget[i]][i]);
return tbl[b][i];
```

Hope it helps!